# dependency injection between modules

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, dagger

in Android project I have two modules:

- app
- core

App module build.gradle is using core module with:

```
 implementation project(':core')
```

So I can use core module classes in app module

In core module I have class A that uses class B (also in core module).
I want to add class C in module App extending class B (or implementing the same interface as B class) and be sure that class A is using class C (not class B). If I not provide class C - my core module must be using class B.

Can Dagger do that magic? If yes, how?